# Create an array with the local paths to multiple images from an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I'm working a project on React and I want the user to select multiple images from an input and display the selected images in a carrousel.

For this I want to create an array with the local paths of said images.

```js
const [localURL, setLocalURl] = useState([]);

const handleFileInput = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.persist();

 for  (let i = 0 ; i < e.target.files.length ; i++) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                let dataURL = reader.result;
                setLocalURl([...localURL, dataURL]);
            }
            reader.onerror = (e) => {
                console.log('error al leer el archivo', e)
            }

       reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i])
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div className="form-group custom-file">
  <label htmlFor="image" className="custom-file-label">File</label>
  <input required className="custom-file-input" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileInput} multiple capture/>

</div>
```

The problem is that I want to save this local file paths to an array, localURL in this case, and pass this as a prop to the carousel component. The localURL only takes the last element of the e.target.file object.

I've tried looping through the object with different funcitons but none of them gives the expected results.

With only one image at a time it works. How do i make it work with multiple files??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get the local path, this could be considered a security issue. You only get the file name. Here is how to get it as an array.

```js
document.querySelector('[type=file]').onchange = function(e) {
    console.log(Array.from(e.target.files, file => file.name));
}
```

```html
<input required className="custom-file-input" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" multiple capture/>
```

Comment: I understand the security issue, But I need a way to store a reference to the file so I can upload it onSubmit and eliminate or add files before upload if the user changes his mind.

How can I create an array with these references so I can preview  and upload the files?

Comment: Array.from(e.target.files, file => file) creates an array of the files. You can do anything you want with it.

Comment: You don't need the function as you are not transforming anything just use `Array.from(e.target.files)`